# Graph Theory - Understanding induced subgraphs

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

> List all ***induced*** subgraphs which are paths of length 4.

My understanding of this question is to list all the combinations of paths (no repeated vertices) of length $4$. For example

$a, b, c, d, e$

$b,c,d,e,f$

$a,d,c,b,h$

and other combinations of paths of $5$ vertices.

Have I understood this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a graph $G = (V, E)$ and for any $W \subset V$, the induced subgraph $G[W]$ contains *all* edges between vertices in $W$. Hence the graph induced on $a, b, c, d, e$ is not actually a path of length 4 since $c$ is also connected to $e$ which forms a loop in the induced subgraph.

Comment: Thanks a ton for making it clear. I've had a lot of trouble understand what is meant by "induced" subgraphs despite reading the definition numerous times. The example really helped.